# Connect higher voltage than power supply to an amplifier

Tags: voltage, amplifier, analog, signal-processing, operational-amplifier

I have a circuit like on this image.I want to reduce 10V signal to (-)1V.
But my op. amp. is powered from 3.3V and **absolute maximum Vcc is 6V**.

Is it save to connect like that?

[image]

Comment: well, guess what "absolute maximum" is trying to say

Comment: The same data sheet also gives you the Max input voltage, and that is typically not higher than supply. So, read your data sheet

Comment: But read the schematic carefully. Is 10V really what the OAmp sees?

Comment: Yes - see your schematic.

Comment: Us read the schematic carefully : it’s you who needs to do that along with the data sheet...

Comment: I've found it in the meantime: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu015/tidu015.pdf you can take a look. They connect -/+15V to amp. that has absolute Vcc of 7V...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can connect higher voltages to the amplifier (entire circuit) than the opamp (chip) absmax rating.

But you must do it with some care.

In normal operation it will work (assuming you take proper care of supply voltage and biassing as in Transistor's answer. Your comments suggest you're aware of the issues so ... good.)

But you must also cover the abnormal cases. 10V on the input when the 3.3V supply is off MAY put the opamp output stage in a high impedance state, translating to 10V on IN- ... boom. (well, inaudibly tiny pop but you get the point).

So refer to the opamp datasheet and design protection mechanisms appropriately - possibly diodes between In- and V+, if the inputs will tolerate being 0.6V above the supply (and the supply is 0.6V below absmax V). If they won't tolerate that, you may need a more complex protection mechanism, perhaps splitting the input resistor into two with the protection diode at the tap.

(NB it is also possible the amplifier already provides such protection diodes, rated for any likely current through that 100K resistor - the datasheet should answer that point)

Comment: +1 for  perhaps splitting the input resistor into two with the protection diode at the tap.

Answer (score 4):

- You have selected an inverting mode amplifier with a gain of 0.1. \$ V_O = -0.1 V_I \$.
- This will work *if* you have a negative supply.

Without a negative supply to the op-amp you cannot get an output voltage less than 0 V.

- If you want a non-inverted signal or only have a single-ended supply then the following might be what you need.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGjFTu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) A divide by 10 attenuator followed by a unity gain non-inverting buffer. (b) A voltage divider.*

Use (a) if you want a buffered signal. Use (b) if you don't need the buffer.

Comment: Well it won't be negative voltage, because I will add another positive voltage to this one (summing amplifier). 
In the meantime I've found this Reference Design from TI: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu015/tidu015.pdf
There's a schematic on the first page and they do it the same as I did (they also add 2.5V to the signal, so it is not negative, I omitted it for readability).

Comment: OK. I don't understand your question or your requirements at all then.